# AngularJS - Do you return the promise or data from the service/factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller, I use a method from a factory to update some data. For example, I'm trying to fetch an updated array of users. Should I be returning the promise itself from the factory? Or should I be returning the data from the promise (not sure if I phrased that correctly)?

I ask because I've seen it both ways, and some people say that the controller shouldn't have to handle whether the request was successful or if it failed. I'm specifically talking about the promise returned from $http in this case.

Or maybe in other words, should I be using the then() method inside the factory, or should I be using it in the controller after returning from the factory?

I've tried to handle the success and error callbacks (using the this() method) from within the service, but when I return the data to the controller, the users array is not properly updated. I'm assuming that's because of the request being async. So in the controller, it would look something like this:

```
vm.users = userFactory.getUsers();
```

If I handle the promise from within the controller, and set the users array within the then() method, it works fine. But this goes back to where I should be using then():

```
userFactory.getUsers().then(
   function(data){
      vm.users = data;
   }, ...
```

Hopefully someone would be able to shed some light on this or provide some input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problem with controller deciding what to do basing on response failing/succeding. In fact it lets you easily handle different cases and doesn't add a lot of overhead to the controller (controller should be as small as possible and focused on current task, but for me going different path whether request failed is the part of its task).

Anyway, in Angular HTTP requests are wrapped in promises internally (I remember that in the previous versions there was a way to automatically unwrap them), so returning from service/factory always returns a promise, which has to be resolved.

I prefer returning a promise from a service/factory because I tend to let other classes decide what to do with the response.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can return the data from the factory (since it's an async call) without using either a `callback` approach (discouraged):

```
userFactory.prototype.getUsers = function(callback){
  $http.get('users').then(function (response) {
      callback(response.data);
  });
};
```

Or the promise approach.

If you're worried about handling the errors on the controller, then worry not! You can handle errors on the service:

```
userFactory.prototype.getUsers = function(){
  return $http.get('users').then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
  }, function(error) {
    // Handle your error here
    return [];
  });
};
```

You can `return` the results of `then` and it will be chained. So things from `service` will execute and `then`, later on, Controller ones.

Comment: And even better approach - you can handle errors by using interceptors on responses and keeping all logic in one place ;)